# PySpark rolling operation with variable ranges

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe looking like this

```
some_data | date   | date_from | date_to
1234      |1-2-2020| 1-2-2020  | 2-2-2020
5678      |2-2-2020| 1-2-2020  | 2-3-2020
```

and I need to perform some operations on `some_data` based on time ranges that are different for every row, and stored in `date_from` and `date_to`. This is basically a rolling operation on `some_data` vs `date`, where the width of the window is not constant.

If the time ranges were the same, like always 7 days preceding/following, I would just do a window with rangeBetween. Any idea how I can still use rangeBetween with these variable ranges? I could really use the partitioning capability Window provides...

My current solution is:

- a join of the table with itself to obtain a secondary/nested `date` column. at this point every `date` has the full list of possible `dates`
- some `where`s to select, for each primary `date` the proper secondary dates according to `date_from` and `date_to`
- a groupby the primary `date` with agg performing the actual operation on the selected rows

But I am afraid this would not be very performant on large datasets. Can this be done with Window? Do you have a better/more performant suggestion?

Thanks a lot,

Andrea.